# Play video on Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, video, osx-yosemite

I have tried to use AVPlayer to play a video with my Cocoa Application. However, it turns out that AVPlayer is capable of playing only a very restricted variety of video types. As an example, .avi files and .flv files will not get played by AVPlayer. I suppose that AVPlayer will play only those video types that Quicktime will play (i.e., quite a few!).

So I was looking for alternatives: I will need my software to play the largest variety possible of videos since I cannot know in advance which kind of videos will my users open.

I have Mac OSX 10.10 (Yosemite). What are the alternatives that are available to me?

Thank you very much indeed

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking AVPlayer only plays Quicktime compatible media.

Things I can think of, off the top of my head (which may / may not be suitable, but I don't know what other restrictions you have):

1. Offer to transcode the video using ffmpeg or similar.
2. See if "Perian" helps (I'm not sure AVPlayer machinery will see it).  Perian is an older Quicktime (32bit) plugin that includes many more codecs. It's deprecated and more or less going away, so it's not a long term solution... if it works at all.